# Extracting pixels from a raster list according to a value range and position in R

Tags: r, conditional

I'm working on a script on R and I have a doubt.
I have a directory with a raster dataset of NDSI MODIS files.
I want to create a list(or stack) of rasters whose first pixel (x=1, y=1) value is between 0.1 and 0.9 from that directory.
I'm a bit lost on how to put conditions in the creation of file lists on R.
To make the list I have used the `list.files` function.

```
setwd("/Desktop/NDSI_MODIS") #Working directory 
modis <- list.files('/Desktop/snowcover_MODIS', pattern = ".tif" ) #list of files
```

The issue is to put the condition on that list.

Comment: Welcome, @Guillermo Rodríguez! If you are in doubt about how to ask, please visit  https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask, consider spending some time in the Markdown help section https://gis.stackexchange.com/editing-help to improve the formatting of your questions. And if you can, help the community!

Comment: raster values are accessed through square brackets: r[][1] would be the first pixel

Answer (score 1):

The filtering cannot be done in your call to `list.files`, you will have to read the files and check one by one and filter out those which do not meet the condition:

```
library(raster)
library(dplyr) 
raster_list = list.files(pattern = "modis", full.names = T)
raster_stack = stack()
for(i in raster_list ) { 
  temp = raster(i)
  if(dplyr::between(temp[][1], 0.1, 0.9))  
    { raster_stack = stack(raster_stack, temp)} else { NULL}
  
  }
```